# L,R,H,D,J relations on a completely simple semi group represented my a rees matrix

Tags: semigroups

I am trying to tackle the following semigroup question. I can't see why my
answer is wrong but I haven't used the fact the semigroup is COMPLETELY
simple anywhere so I think there must be an error somewhere in my proof.
Any advice?

**Question**

Consider a completely simple semigroup S, represented as a Rees matrix 
semigroup $M[G; I, \Lambda; P]$ over a
group $G$. Prove that

$(i, g, l) \mathrel{\mathcal{L}} (j, h, m) \iff l = m$

$(i, g, l) \mathrel{\mathcal{R}} (j, h, m) \iff i = j$

$(i, g, l) \mathrel{\mathcal{H}} (j, h, m) \iff i = j \text{ and } l = m$

$\mathcal{D} = \mathcal{J} = S \times S$.

**Attempted Answer**

Let $S$ be completely simple, recall this means $S$ has no proper two-sided ideals
but has minimal left and right ideals.

(i,g,l)$\mathcal{L}$(j,h,m)$\iff\exists s=(a.b.c),t=(d,e,f) \in S$ such that
$(a.b.c)(i,g, l)=(j,h,m)$ and $(d,e,f)(j,h,m)=(i,g, l)$

$\iff (a, bP_{ci}g, l)=(j,h,u)$ and $(d,eP_{fj}h,m)=(i, g, l)$

$\iff a=j, d=i, l=m, bP_{ci}g=h, eP_{fj}h=g$

Now $a,b,c,d,e,f $ are arbitrary we can select these values to satisfy the
above equations thus the only necessary and sufficient condition is that
$l= m$.

A similar proof then works for the $\mathcal{R}$ relation, and we use the
fact that $\mathcal{H}$ related $\iff$ both $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{R}$
are related to do the third part.

Next onto $D$, we recall that $D= \mathcal{L} \circ R=R \circ \mathcal{L}$
and thus $(\alpha,\beta) \in J \iff (\alpha,\beta) \in \mathcal{L} \circ R
\iff \exists u \in S\ $ such that $\alpha \mathrel{\mathcal{L}} u \mathrel{\mathcal{R}} \beta\ $.

Now letting $\alpha=(a,b,c) , u=(d,e,f), \beta=(g,h,i)$ we observe that we
need $(a,b,c) \mathrel{\mathcal{L}} (d,e,f) \mathrel{\mathcal{R}} (g,h,i)
\iff c=f, d=g\ $ but $u$ is an arbitrary element so we can always make this
happen thus all elements are $\mathcal{D}$-related.

Lastly onto $\mathcal{J}$ relation. $(a,b) \in \mathcal{J} \iff$ they
generate the same two-sided ideal. However $S$ is simple so the only
two-sided ideal is $S$ itself as there are no proper two-sided ideals, thus
all elements generate the same two-sided ideal so all elements are $\mathcal{J}$
related.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof seems to be correct, so the problem has another nature: by [Rees’ characterization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rees_matrix_semigroup#Rees.27_theorem), a semigroup is completely simple if and only if it is isomorphic to a Rees matrix semigroup over a group.